# SSL verification for registry.gitlab.com via httplib2 fails

Tags: gitlab, httplib2

I use bazel to publish docker images to gitlab regitry. Last week, the bazel commands started failing. I was able to narrow down the issue to httplib2.

The code sample below can be used to reproduce the issue.

```
import httplib
import httplib2

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("registry.gitlab.com")
conn.request("GET", "/")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print r1.status, r1.reason

httplib2.Http().request('https://registry.gitlab.com')
```

The output for the above is:

```
200 OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deleteMe.py", line 9, in <module>
    httplib2.Http().request('https://registry.gitlab.com')
  File "/Users/joint/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 2135, in request
    cachekey,
  File "/Users/joint/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1796, in _request
    conn, request_uri, method, body, headers
  File "/Users/joint/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1701, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/joint/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1411, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)
```

Error shown in Wireshark is 'Description: Unknown CA (48)'

I have tried verifying the gitlab certs via openssl and I don't see any issue with them.

I have tried specifying the gitlab cert in httplib2 definition but I get the same error.

```
  h = httplib2.Http(ca_certs='./registrygitlabcom.crt')
  h.request('https://registry.gitlab.com')
```

Any pointers on what I should be doing or trying out... thanks!

Comment: The issue seems to be the root certificate in the certificate chain. I was able to get the code to work by adding USERTrustRSACertificationAuthority.crt - which is the root certificate. 

However, I am not sure why adding this certificate resolves the problem - as opposed to the other two. What is specifically wrong with the root certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured out the answer. Posting it here for anyone else who might run into this.

The root certificates used by httplib2 are coming from the cacerts.txt file.
(https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2/blob/master/python2/httplib2/cacerts.txt)

registry.gitlab.com probably switched the root CA last week and that has triggered the problem.